# Using PHP to create dynamic forms with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've searched the site and was unable to find an answer.

What I get in my script is an empty pulldown menu instead of the contents from the MySQL table. I'm developing/testing code in NetBeans 8.0.2 and running in Firefox 34.0.5. Here is my code (name of file is 'domains.php') and it is exactly as shown; I didn't leave anything out.

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<select id="domain" name="domain">

<?php

// define connection variables
$DBServer = "localhost"; // server name or IP address
$DBUser = "xxxxxxxxx";
$DBPass = "xxxxxxxxx";
$DBName = "country";
$DBPort = "3306";        

// create a connection to mysql
$conn = mysqli_connect ($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName, $DBPort);

// check to see if a connection was made and, if yes, proceed
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { // connection failed
    echo "Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// the domain query to get all domain names
$domainQuery = "select domains from domains_subdomains_cop";

// run the query -- this works elsewhere to display the contents of a table
$resultD = mysqli_query($conn, $domainQuery) or die ("Query to get data from domain failed: "
   . mysql_error());

// w/the exception of pulldown menu, the while loop works well to display records
// I've seen examples with MYSQLI_ASSOC and without it and I've tried both without success for
// pulldown menus. I use it because I haven't had any issues elsewhere in my program.

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultD, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $domainName=$row[DOMAINS]; // DOMAINS is the table attribute I'm trying to pull from
    echo "<option>
       $domainName  // I accidentely put a ';' here once and that did show up in the pulldown
                    // menu.
    </option>";
}

?>

</select>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs; they don't mix together; *period*.

Comment: As Fred is saying, specifically `mysql_fetch_array` is your problem as well as you have a `mysql_error` in there too.

Comment: Also in your query you call the column `domains` (all lowercase) but in your fetch you have `$row[DOMAINS]`.  I believe this is case sensitive and you need to match it how MySQL has the table column named.

Comment: @Mooseknuckles True. OP writes in code though *`// DOMAINS is the table attribute I'm trying to pull from`* - So, it's hard to say which one is the actual lettercase he should use. Either way, OP should be using all the same APIs and in order to catch the real error.

Comment: Definitely, first fix the mixing of mysql and mysqli.  Then if that doesn't fix it my comment was meant as something else that may be causing problems. :D

Comment: Aside from your case issues, keys in associative arrays should use strings. So unless `DOMAINS` is a defined constant, quote your key: `$row['DOMAINS']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an object-oriented,      mysqli prepared statements version

```
<form method="post" action="">
<select id="domain" name="domain">
<?php
$db = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName, $DBPort);
$stmt = $db->prepare("select `domains` from `domains_subdomains_cop`");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo "<option>".$row->domains."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: *Show a man how to fish, feed him for life.* This, only feeds him for a day.

Comment: Thank you, all! Fred, your comments were correct - mixed APIs (corrected) and Mooseknuckles, you were correct with mixed tense (upper/lower case) (corrected). I didn't, however, need to quote $row[DOMAINS]. Magna, your code helped a lot!  Again, I want to thank you all as I pulled pieces of code from various places which, obviously, was wrong. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Scott You're welcome Scott. I guess our comments did serve you well after all ;-)